# STR_TO_DATE and SUBSTRING in it

Tags: mysql

Hi I would like to combine 3 substrings (year,month and day) from one string and put whole concatenation as date format,but I don't know what I am doing wrong. All characters of string are numbers (11).

```
SELECT str_to_date('SELECT CONCAT(substring(String,1,2),
                                  substring(String,3,2),
                                  substring(String,5,2)) 
                    FROM table', '%y %m %d');
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with a single substring call:

```
SELECT
    STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(String, 6), '%y%m%d')
FROM yourTable;
```

Note: You should avoid storing date information as plain text.  My usual advice here would be to keep the data returned from `STR_TO_DATE` as a separate column, and then remove the text date column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `String` is a column name in your table. You do not need to specify `SELECT .. FROM table` inside the `Concat()` function. You can directly use the column values inside the function. Your approach was syntactically wrong as well. `FROM table` should be after the `SELECT ..` clause.

Now, in the specified date format `'%y %m %d'`, there are spaces between **yy**, **mm** and **dd**. So either you will need to use spaces in-between during the concatenation:

```
SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT(substring(String,1,2), ' ',
                          substring(String,3,2), ' ',
                          substring(String,5,2)
                         )
                   , '%y %m %d')
FROM table
```

Or, you can get rid of the spaces from the format specified.

```
SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT(substring(String,1,2),
                          substring(String,3,2),
                          substring(String,5,2)
                         )
                   , '%y%m%d')
FROM table
```